# How to suppress "No input paths specified in job" and return an empty RDD / DataFrame instead?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am writing an in-house API to ease use of Spark with custom measuring data formats. Since the schemas used are different depending on the type of the measuring data, I am using the `DataFrame` API, and I am using Hadoop's `FileInputFormat` alongside `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` to read them, as the measuring data formats cannot be reduced to simple text files.

In my API, I want to return empty `DataFrame`s instead of throwing the `No input paths specified in job` exception, so I first went with the naïve approach:

```
try
  spark
    .sparkContext
    .newAPIHadoopFile(inPath,
                      classOf[OneOfMyCustomMeasuringDataInputFormat],
                      classOf[SomeAppropriateKeyWritable],
                      classOf[SomeAppropriateValueWritable],
                      conf)
    .map {
           case (k, v) => SomeAppropriateRecordCaseClass(/* data from k and v */)
         }
    .toDF
  catch {
    case e: IOException if e.getMessage.equals("No input paths specified in job") =>
    spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row],
                          // Some implicits I made to simplify schema construction:
                          ("foo" of SomeType) ::
                          ("bar" of SomeOtherType) ::
                          // more ::
                          Nil : StructType)
  }
```

However, as RDDs are lazy, when there are no input paths, this exception doesn't fire until the DF is really accessed.

Currently, I handle this in all my `FileInputFormat`s and instructed my colleagues who might add more formats in the future to check for this exception in the `listStatus` method and return an empty list, but I wonder if this can be done more in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through Hadoop's and Spark's source code, I saw that as it is currently coded, really the best solution is currently to handle this in the `FileInputFormat`s. I added an extra option that is put into my Hadoop `Configuration`, named `FileInputFormat.dontThrowOnEmptyPaths`, and my custom input formats honor this. They catch the respective `IOException` as in my code example above, and only rethrow it if this option is not set or if it is set to `false`.

It's sort of a workaround, [I posted an enhancement suggestion to the JIRA about this.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23395)